# Total budget of Nuremberg trial

Tags: world-war-two, nazi-germany, law

I am trying to estimate the total budget of the Nuremberg War Criminal trial. Any help with reference, please?

Comment: It will be good even if someone can give me partial info.

Comment: Just curious: what is the context of the question?

Comment: @FelixGoldberg, I was trying to understand whether the Bangladesh government is allocating enough fund to the international crimes tribunal of Bangladesh.

Comment: Well, in that case, don't forget to adjust the 1946 figure for inflation, once you have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although not exactly answering, following resource has some important information. Skilbeck, Rupert. "Funding Justice: The Price of War Crimes Trials." Human Rights Brief 15, no. 3 (2008): 6-10.

Summary:

1. In the second half of 2008, the trial of Thomas Dyilo
   Lubanga was originally expected to commence at the
   International Criminal Court (ICC),1 five years after the
   Court commenced operations. The ICC’s 2007 budget was $146
   million (93 million euros), leaving it still some way behind
   the $1.2 billion (762 million euros) and $1 billion (635 million
   euros) spent by the International Criminal Tribunal for the
   former Yugoslavia (ICTY) and International Criminal Tribunal
   for Rwanda (ICTR) respectively in their ten years of operation,
   a cost of between $10–15 million (6.4–9.5 million euros) per
   accused.
2. The Court of Bosnia and Herzegovina
   (BiH) in Sarajevo is running a large number of internationalized
   trials at $709,000 (450,000 euros) per trial, which is predicted to
   reduce to $236,000 (150,000 euros) over the next two years.
3. The Special Panels of East Timor's 2001
   budget was $6.3 million (4 million euros), $6 million (3.8 million
   euros) of which was allocated to the prosecution, with
   only $300,000 (190,000 euros) for the rest of the court.3 The
   2003–2005 budget was $14,358,600 (9,116,340 euros), even
   less when divided annually.
4. The original budget for the ECCC of Cambodia was $56 million (35.5
   million euros), with $13 million (8.25 million euros) provided
   by the Government of Cambodia and $43 million (27.3 million
   euros) provided by the international community through voluntary
   donations. During 2007 it became clear that the ECCC had no hope of
   completing the trials within the original timescale and budget.
   In March 2008 a new request for funding was presented to
   donors, extending the lifespan of the Court until March 2011 and
   requesting an additional $115 million (73 million euros), taking
   the total budget to almost $170 million (108 million euros).
   With only five accused, this created a cost per trial of $36 million
   (23 million euros).
5. In the case of Bosnia and Herzegovina, the
   government provided $4.7 million (3 million euros) in 2005 and
   plans to provide approximately $15.8 million (10 million euros)
   annually by 2010. A separate donor-funded budget funds the
   international staff, which amounted to $15.8 million (10 million
   euros) in 2006, reducing to $7.9 million (5 million euros)
   in 2009. There was a pre-trial cost of approximately $708,000 (450,000 euros)
   in 2006 reducing to $236,000 (150,000 euros) in 2010.

Comment: Could you please summarize?

Comment: @FelixGoldberg, I am little busy right now. I will try to summarize next weekend.

Comment: Ok, no pressure. +1 for now, in advance :)

Comment: @FelixGoldberg, done!

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer: [this page](http://avalon.law.yale.edu/imt/imtconst.asp) indicates that the trials were paid for by the  Control Council of Germany, aka [Allied Control Council](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allied_Control_Council). I couldn't find an online budget for the council, but perhaps the printed 9 volumes of its papers, duly mentioned in the wiki article, contain this information.